# Creating CSS Breadcrumb with Image Demo

Tags: css

I am facing an issue with creating a CSS breadcrumb and I am in need of assistance from the Stack Overflow community. To provide a better understanding of my problem, I would like to share a demo image.

The demo image showcases a breadcrumb layout that I'm trying to achieve. It includes hierarchical subcategories and parent categories, along with hover effects and transitions between items. I want to recreate this structure and effects using CSS, but I'm having difficulty applying the appropriate CSS rules.

I would greatly appreciate any help and suggestions from the community on how to create a breadcrumb similar to the demo image. Any sample code, guidance, or hints to help me achieve the desired outcome would be highly appreciated.

Thank you all for taking the time to read and support.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p34nt.png)

The design file showcases a breadcrumb layout with intricate shapes, gradients, and precise positioning that I am trying to replicate using CSS. However, my attempts thus far have fallen short, and I am unable to achieve the same level of fidelity.